# React get and show attached files in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, carrierwave

seems a simple problem but, i don't know why this is causing a little stress, anyway.

here is situation:

after get the attachments on the Post.show in rails

```
  async getAttachments() {
    // this.setState({showProgress: true})
    let auth_token = window.localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
    let post_id = this.props.match.params.id;
    fetch(`/posts/${post_id}/attachments`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Access: auth_token
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          attachments: json.attachments,

          image: json.attachments.image,
          thumb: json.attachments.image.thumb,
          url: json.attachments.thumb.url
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

i decide to render it as usual

with `{this.state.attachments}`

but did not rendered.

so i tried to map and then i tried

```
   var attachments = this.state.attachments.map(a => {
      return (
        <div key={a.id}>
          <img source={a.thumb} />

          <img source={a.url}>{a.url}</img>
        </div>
      );
    });
```

the thing is ever rails carrierwave attachment/files. create a object inside the array and many people still have doubt how to grab and render these files.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `image` tag uses an attribute named `src`, not `source`.  That's your problem.

Aside: Consider this snippet of your code:

```
this.setState({
  attachments: json.attachments,        // OK, keep  

  image: json.attachments.image,        // bad path into the object  
  thumb: json.attachments.image.thumb,  // bad path into the object  
  url: json.attachments.thumb.url       // bad path into the object
});
```

The three lines starting with `image`, `thumb`, and `attachment` should be deleted.

The result of using the code without deleting those lines will be that your state looks like:

```
{
  attachments:  <an array of attachments>,  // correct, wanted, should keep  
  image: undefined,
  thumb: undefined,  
  url: undefined
}
```

This is because `json.attachments` is an array so it does not have any data at the paths you are calling.  By "path into the object" I merely mean a sequence of keys to call in sequence of dot notation.